# Twitter card on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, twitter-card

Step # 1 : Added the meta tags in my header.php

```
<?php if (is_single()){ 
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
    ?>
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php echo get_the_title() ?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo get_the_excerpt() ?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo $image[0] ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Step # 2 : On Twitter click added

```
<?php
    $link = empty($twitter_username) ? 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$title.'&amp;url='.$url : 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$title.'&amp;url='.$url. '&amp;via='.$twitter_username;
?>

    <li>
       <a onclick="popupCenter('<?php echo $link; ?>', 600, 300);" class="share-link" style="margin-left : <?php echo $spaceBetweenIcons-4?>px !important"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
   </li>
```

Step # 3: I tweet this url

Step # 4 : check on card validator I get following logs 
INFO:  Page fetched successfully 
INFO:  8 metatags were found 
INFO:  twitter:card = summary tag found 
INFO:  Card loaded successfully

Step # 5 : Go to twitter

On twitter I only see the TEXT of url even on view detail ..

I dont what am i missing please help .. with description thanks in Advance :)

Comment: did you figure out the issue?